# RSS Reader that displays images and colored text

Tags: gratis, rss

I'm generating a feed using PHP for my website but I can't get it to display as I intend in any RSS readers I can find as it uses both colored text and images.

I am seeking an RSS Reader that

1. Displays images
2. Displays colored text
3. Preferably a Firefox add-on, but not required. Must run on Windows; can also be a web app.

For reference: NewsFox allows colored text but not images, Sage allows images but not colored text.

Is there any reader that allows both?

Comment: If it’s not a Firefox add-on: any OS requirement? Can it also be a web app? Gratis? Open Source?

Comment: It has to be free and be able to be run on Windows (so I guess web is fine).

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's built in RSS reader displays both images and any standard css formating.

For example: (I added the colouring to that line of text with a simple "color:red;" inline-style attribute) since I couldn't think offhand of any feeds that regularly had colour text as well as images.
[image: reader screenie]

Comment: When I navigate to the feed using Firefox it does not display the colored text. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: @user69 It should just work. What Version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: In help it says 28.0.

Comment: that *should* work fine - what code are you using to set the text colour?

Comment: I've tried with <span><font color=red and <span style="color:red. Both work with NewsFox (which, of course, doesn't display images)